# Linux Socket & IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP

Tags: sockets, udp, multicast

Scenario:

Process 1 creates a socket and subscribes to a multicast group using the IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP option [Group: 224.0.0.30 Source: 192.168.0.1 Device:eth0]. Binds the socket to 224.0.0.30:5555.

Process 2 creates a socket and subscribes to a multicast group using the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option [Group: 224.0.0.30 Device: eth0]. Binds the socket to 224.0.0.30:5555.

Both processes are running simultaneously on the same box.

A source with IP 172.10.1.1 sends a packet with multicast destination 224.0.0.30:5555.

Will process 1 receive the multicast packet? Or will it be filtered out by the kernel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 7 ip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

> `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP (since Linux 2.4.22 / 2.5.68)
>                Join a multicast group and allow receiving data only from a
>                specified source.`,,,

This means that your first process will not receive packets sent from source `172.10.1.1`.
But reading further:

> ... This option can be used multiple times to allow receiving data from more than one source.

, which might be useful for you.